# How can we customize the default warnings in Spartacus?

Tags: warnings, customization, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

When an unauthorized user in Spartacus wants to log in and open PLP, the following default warning is displayed automatically.

This error is in default:
.../spartacus-develop/projects/assets/src/translations/en/common.ts

**How can I customize this field in this file? When this happens, I want him to write another text.**

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this section in the Spartacus Documentation should help you: [Overwriting Individual Translations](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/i18n/#overwriting-individual-translations)